# I'm getting an undefined model in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, model, undefined

I have this code:

```
    var Day        = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            service: 'None',
            concert: 'None',
            bible:   'None',
            social:  'None',
            play:    'None'
        }
    }),

    Day_view   = Backbone.View.extend({

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html('Service:' + this.model.service + '<br />Concert:' + this.model.concert + '<br />Bible:' + this.model.bible + '<br />Social:' + this.model.social + '<br />Play:' + this.model.play);
            return this;
        } 
    }),

    day_view = new Day_view({model: new Day({service: '10', concert: '11', bible:   '11', social:  '13', play:    '14' })});
    alert(day_view.render().$el.html());
```

And I get this:

Service:undefined  Concert:undefined Bible:undefined Social:undefined Play:undefined

Where is the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you access attributes in Backbone is through `get` :

```
this.model.get('service')
```

Comment: Forgot about the model (its not JSON)... or I can use model = this.model.toJSON and then use model.service

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is throwing that undefined error because you are not defining the `el` of the view. You have to pass a DOM element to the Backbone view as a hook point to insert the html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Day = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            service: 'None',
            concert: 'None',
            bible:   'None',
            social:  'None',
            play:    'None'
        }
    }),

    Day_view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html('Service:' + this.model.get('service') + '<br />Concert:' + this.model.get('concert') + '<br />Bible:' + this.model.get('bible') + '<br />Social:' + this.model.get('social') + '<br />Play:' + this.model.get('play'));
            return this;
        } 
    }),

    day_view = new Day_view({model: new Day({service: '10', concert: '11', bible:   '11', social:  '13', play:    '14' })});
    alert(day_view.render().$el);
});
```